# Problemas al ejecutar curl (PHP)

Tags: php, json, curl

Estoy desarrollando una API para conectarme al sistema de pago de Braspag. Verificando el manual de división de pagos, en la parte sobre Solicitud - Transacción de crédito, json se muestra de la siguiente manera:

**Request:**

```
--header "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
{  
   "merchantorderid":"23082019",
   "customer": {
        "Name": "Comprador Accept",
        "email": "comprador@teste.com.br",
        "Identity": "12750233713",
        "identitytype": "CPF",
        "Mobile": "5521996660078"
    },
    "payment": {
        "type": "splittedcreditcard",
        "amount": 10000,
        "capture": true,
        "installments": 1,
        "softdescriptor": "teste",
        "CreditCard": {
            "cardNumber": "4481530710186111",
            "holder": "Oswaldo Soares",
            "ExpirationDate": "12/2019",
            "SecurityCode": "693",
            "Brand": "Visa",
            "SaveCard": "false"
        },
        "fraudanalysis": {
            "provider": "cybersource", 
            "Shipping": {
                "Addressee": "Comprador Accept"
            },
            "browser": {
                "ipaddress": "179.221.103.151",
                "browserfingerprint": "22082019"
            },
            "totalorderamount": 10000,
            "cart": {
                "isgift": false,
                "returnsaccepted": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "Produto teste",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "sku": 563,
                        "unitprice": 100.00
                    }
                ]
            },
            "MerchantDefinedFields": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Value": "Guest"
                }
            ]
        }
   }
}
```

Y en PHP lo pongo de esta manera:

```
    public function Autorizacao()
    {
      $autorizar = [
            "merchantorderid" => '33424356',
            "customer" => [
                                "Name" => "Comprador Accept",
                                "email" => "comprador@teste.com.br",
                                "Identity" => "12750233713",
                                "identitytype" => "CPF",
                                "Mobile" => "5521996660078"
                            ],
             "payment" => [
                            "type" => "splittedcreditcard",
                            "amount" => 10000,
                            "capture" => true,
                            "installments" => 1,
                            "softdescriptor" => "teste",
                            "CreditCard" => [
                                                "cardNumber" => "4481530710186111",
                                                "holder" => "Oswaldo Soares",
                                                "ExpirationDate" => "12/2019",
                                                "SecurityCode" => "693",
                                                "Brand" => "Visa",
                                                "SaveCard" => "false"
                                            ],
                            "fraudanalysis" => [
                                                "provider" => "cybersource", 
                                                "Shipping" => [
                                                                    "Addressee" => "Comprador Accept"
                                                                ],
                                                "browser" => [
                                                                "ipaddress" => "179.221.103.151",
                                                                "browserfingerprint" => "22082019"
                                                                ],
                                                "totalorderamount" => 10000,
                                                "cart" => [
                                                            "isgift" => false,
                                                            "returnsaccepted" => true,
                                                            "items" => [
                                                                        "name" => "Produto teste",
                                                                        "quantity" => 1,
                                                                        "sku" => 563,
                                                                        "unitprice" => 100.00                                                   
                                                                    ]
                                                        ],
                                                "MerchantDefinedFields" => [
                                                                            "Id" => 1,
                                                                            "Value" => "Guest"
                                                                        ]
                                                ]
                           ]
         ];
         var_dump($autorizar);
         $campos = json_encode($autorizar);
         $merchantID = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
         $clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
         $url = 'https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/';
         $curl = curl_init($url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $campos);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.base64_encode($merchantID . ':' . $clientSecret).' ', "cache-control: no-cache"]);
         $response   = curl_exec($curl);
         $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         var_dump($curl);
         if($statusCode == 200){
             $response = json_decode($response);
         }else{
             return  "Erro: " .curl_error($curl);
         }         
   curl_close($curl);  
    }
```

Cuando se ejecuta directamente en el navegador y se ve por el código fuente, no devuelve el error y la matriz se ve así. Se ve diferente de lo que aparece en el manual:

```
 array(3) {
      ["merchantorderid"]=>
      string(16) "2313213214556666"
      ["customer"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(16) "Comprador Accept"
        ["email"]=>
        string(22) "comprador@teste.com.br"
        ["Identity"]=>
        string(11) "12750233713"
        ["identitytype"]=>
        string(3) "CPF"
        ["Mobile"]=>
        string(13) "5521996660078"
      }
      ["payment"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(18) "splittedcreditcard"
        ["amount"]=>
        int(10000)
        ["capture"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["installments"]=>
        int(1)
        ["softdescriptor"]=>
        string(5) "teste"
        ["CreditCard"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["cardNumber"]=>
          string(16) "4481530710186111"
          ["holder"]=>
          string(14) "Oswaldo Soares"
          ["ExpirationDate"]=>
          string(7) "12/2019"
          ["SecurityCode"]=>
          string(3) "693"
          ["Brand"]=>
          string(4) "Visa"
          ["SaveCard"]=>
          string(5) "false"
        }
        ["fraudanalysis"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["provider"]=>
          string(11) "cybersource"
          ["Shipping"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["Addressee"]=>
            string(16) "Comprador Accept"
          }
          ["browser"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["ipaddress"]=>
            string(15) "179.221.103.151"
            ["browserfingerprint"]=>
            string(8) "22082019"
          }
          ["totalorderamount"]=>
          int(10000)
          ["cart"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["isgift"]=>
            bool(false)
            ["returnsaccepted"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["items"]=>
            array(4) {
              ["name"]=>
              string(13) "Produto teste"
              ["quantity"]=>
              int(1)
              ["sku"]=>
              int(563)
              ["unitprice"]=>
              float(100)
            }
          }
          ["MerchantDefinedFields"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["Value"]=>
            string(5) "Guest"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    resource(6) of type (curl)
   ERRO <br> Status: 500
```

El error de estado 500 es Error interno del servidor. No tengo experiencia con CURL y Json / PHP. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Muchas gracias y perdón por mi español.

Comment: Se ve como arreglo porque estás haciendo `var_dump($autorizar);` antes de convertir a JSON. Para ver lo que realmente envías deberías poner 2 líneas abajo `var_dump($campos);`

Comment: Tienes razón, Triby. Gracias. Ahora aparece el formato correcto, pero sigue dando el error 500. Sería un problema para ellos, ¿verdad?

Comment: Efectivamente, el error no parece ser de tu lado. Te sugiero enviar un ticket de soporte para que te digan lo que está fallando.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby.